# Get JSON data from multiple files in a unique response

Tags: json, node.js, express

There are several files containing JSON data on my server. I want to receive the data contained in those files with a single GET request.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
app.get('/json', function(req, res){

    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/file01.json', function(err, content){
        var data01 = content;
    });

    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/file02.json', function(err, content){
        var data02 = content;
    });

    res.send({file01: data01, file02: data02});

});
```

I know this is absolutely not the way to do it, the files are still being read when the response is sent, and i'm not sure if data01 and data02 are globally defined.

But then, what is the way to do it?

Should I use a stream? Should I use multiple `res.write()` instead? Enlighten me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perfect fit for [`async.parallel`](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel).

```
var async = require('async');
app.get('/json', function(req, res) {
  var work = {
    file01: async.apply(fs.readFile, __dirname + '/file01.json'),
    file02: async.apply(fs.readFile, __dirname + '/file02.json')
  };
  async.parallel(work, function (error, results) {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error);
      return;
    }
    //might need string->Object here
    results['file01'] = JSON.parse(results['file01']);
    results['file02'] = JSON.parse(results['file02']);
    res.send(results);
  });
});
```

Comment: This is excellent! I am receiving weird arrays of numbers as a response though. How can I parse the results properly?

Comment: Well you are reading the data as strings and not parsing it into an Object. I would think it would work anyway, but maybe you need to `JSON.parse` string->Object and then express will stringify it on the way out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the callback of each `readFile` to do the next operation:

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/file01.json', function(err, content){
    var data01 = content;
    //Might be smart to do some err checking here
    //if (err) send error
    //else read the next file
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/file02.json', function(err, content){
        //if (err) again
        var data02 = content;
        res.send({file01: data01, file02: data02});
    });
});
```